# unable to open a file with nano and vi in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

when I try to open a file with nano or vi in ubuntu ,they show me nothing but the file exist in the path.

```
nano conf/hadoop-env.sh
```

Why ?

Comment: What does `cat conf/hadoop-env.sh` show?

Comment: nothing and file or folder not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're in the right directory?

Run `ls`.  If it shows you a `conf` folder, run `ls conf`.  While there may be a `conf/hadoop-env.sh` somewhere, it's not in the current directory

You should find it at `<hadoop installation directory>/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh`, but I don't know where you installed hadoop.

Comment: I see the hadoop folder in the path but when run ls I cant see hadoop folder

Comment: and it sayas Access to the conf is not possible